# zip4j produces zip with all files' size = 0

Tags: java, zip, zip4j

I have a problem generating ZIP files via `zip4j`.

I am able to produce ZIP archive using following code (I omitted some parts, that are not related to the issue), which is basically taken from `zip4j` tutorial:

```
File zipFile = new File(zipName);
ZipParameters params = new ZipParameters();
params.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
params.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
try (ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile))) {
   for (/* loop through list of input data */) {
        String outputName = /* method to determine file name */;
        try (InputStream in = /* method to get IS */ ) {
            params.setFileNameInZip(outputName);
            File tmpEntry = new File(outputName);
            tmpEntry.createNewFile();
            out.putNextEntry(tmpEntry, params);
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            tmpEntry.delete();
            out.closeEntry();
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that although all files are correctly included in ZIP archive, their declared file size is 0. I can unzip them using "dumb" ZIP readers (like build-in TotalCommander's one), because all data are actually here, but more "clever" programs (like 7zip) produce CRC error and refuse to open them as corrupted.

I would say I need to declare the file size somehow (and I am definitely not doing this in my code snippet), but I was unable to find the (probably obvious) solution. I have googled that native `java.util.zip.ZipEntry` has `.setSize()` method, but I don't see anything like this in `zip4j`...

Anyone knows the correct approach to this?

Comment: Create a new ZipParameters inside the loop for every putNextEntry. BTW remove `in.close();`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the output is still the same - all files show size = 0

Comment: I do not know zip4j but still a suggestion: call `out.closeEntry()` before `tmpEntry.delete()`. The latter could be the culprit for a zero size.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately that didn't do the job either :(

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is quite simple. One just needs to add following setting into `ZipParameters`:

```
params.setSourceExternalStream(true);
```

How I found that?

I digged deeper into the code and find following in `closeEntry()` method of `CipherOutputStream.java` class of `zip4j`:

```
if (zipParameters.isSourceExternalStream()) {
    fileHeader.setUncompressedSize(totalBytesRead);
    if (localFileHeader.getUncompressedSize() != totalBytesRead) {
        localFileHeader.setUncompressedSize(totalBytesRead);
    }
}
```

This is the only place where `setUncompressedSize()` - which sounds like having something to do with declared file size - method is called. So I got suspicious and tried to set the parameter in my code. And it does the job.

The lesson learned is that [this example](https://github.com/dmp/zip4j/blob/master/src/net/lingala/zip4j/examples/zip/CreateZipWithOutputStreams.java) of using `zip4j` is incorrect because it is missing that vital line of code.